# how do you use threejs WITHOUT using node.js, express, or a build tool?

Tags: javascript, three.js

Goal: import the modules and get going...

Problem: the jsm stuff like OrbitControls.js import `from 'three';` which results in an error:

`[Error] TypeError: Module specifier, 'three' does not start with "/", "./", or "../". promiseReactionJob`

Suggestions range anywhere from manually copying the files out of node_modules and modifying the path, to waiting for browsers to support naked paths. In the meantime however I'd really like to get on with my life and use the tool on a standard server...

What's the best practice for NON node servers here?

Comment: Have you read and tried _"Install from CDN or static hosting"_ from https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/Installation?

Comment: Yes I tried this, but it's difficult to reliably track down/use the jsm stuff on a CDN and the docs offer no guidance really...

Answer (score 0):

The offical answer is that these jsm components are listed under "examples" for a reason, you are supposed to duplicate and edit them for your own app, so swapping in absolute paths is completely fine.

Generally I prefer to not touch anything in the node_modules folder, but in this case it's actually recommended by three.js

[You can read more about module resolution here](https://medium.com/threejs/module-specifiers-versus-relative-import-references-fd747980ba6f).